# SCVMM 2012 SP1 P2V Conversion

Tags: scvmm

I was wondering if anyone can help with this.

I have SCVMM 2012 SP1, and I want to do a P2V conversion of a 2008 R2 server with a number of hard drives, both interval as well as DAS.  I do not have one location on the host large enough, but do have enough space across both internal space as well as DAS.  Can the P2V wizard handle this scenario, or would I need to get involved with Powershell scripting for this?  I may want the C: and E: drives from the source server on the E: drive of the host, etc.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't select multiple host paths during the P2V. What you could do is to run the P2V twice (using different target guest names for each one). The first time selecting only one guest volume to convert and the second time selecting the other guest volume to convert, making sure to select the appropriate host path for each P2V. Then when both conversions are done simply delete the second P2V guest and add its volume to the first P2V. Removing/deleting a guest does not delete the virtual hard disk files so this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Joe.  I was hoping for something easy, like being able to use the wizard, but I suppose I can do as you suggest or do the P2V of my OS volume and other critical volumes and then Disk2vhd the others.